# How to move view based on device motion in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-motion

Based on device movement i need to set the frames to the view. I had tried using core motion, there I'm getting x, y, z values, but unable to get device moved distance based on those coordinates.

```
[self.manager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion * _Nullable motion, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    xValue = motion.userAcceleration.x;
    yValue = motion.userAcceleration.y;
    zValue = motion.userAcceleration.z;

}];
```

Comment: Did you consider using yaw, pitch and roll instead of just x, y and z? These data you can get from the `CMDeviceMotion`'s `attitude` property.

Comment: Yes i tried with those too, but unable to calculate.

Comment: Check my answer. For what I understand about your question you want to calculate distance itself like cm, inches or whatever and this is "not possible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is you can try to calculate this distance but you'll have too much error, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k).

You didn't state what you're really trying to do, so if you trying to create the parallax effect you can use `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`.

Comment: Just to keep it documented, were you trying to create the parallax effect or the video answered your question? Also if the answer is ok for you, please accept the answer, so we can keep improving the comunity :)